# Lumen routes not working without index.php

Tags: php, apache, vagrant, laravel-5.1, lumen

I have lumen installed in Vagrant VM (ubunty/trusty64). in my Vagrantfile have enabled   `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"`

My directory structure inside VM is

```
var
 - www
  -html
   -app
   -bootstrap
   -database
   .... so on.
```

I made a virtual host inside VM `/etc/apache2/sites-available/api.dukaan.pk` with below contents

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@api.dukaan.pk
    ServerName api.dukaan.pk
    ServerAlias www.api.dukaan.pk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then i enabled it with `sudo a2ensite api.dukaan.pk.conf`. Restarted apache several times no luck.

Then in my host machine Windows 10 i put `192.168.33.10 api.dukaan.pk`

Now in my app/Http/routes.php i defined two routes

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->welcome();
});
$app->get('/hello', function() {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

If i go to `http://api.dukaan.pk/index.php/hello` It works but if i remove index.ph from this url like `http://api.dukaan.pk/hello` it shows 404 page not found error.

There is default .htaccess and index.php file in my `app/public` directory.

Please help me getting rid of this index.php file

Thanks

Comment: care to post `.htaccess` that come along with `index.php`?

Comment: `.htaccess` will not make a 404 error ?

Comment: I added `AllowOverride All` line in my `api.dukaan.pk.conf` and now its working fine. But i don't know what i did its just a copy paste. If any one of you can post a answer explaining the reason so that it will help other people also. Thanks

Comment: based on the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) **When this directive is set to All, then any directive which has the .htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess files.** perhaps you should post your solution as an answer, it might help someone else. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the apache instance running in your VM, the VHost you defined run in port `80`. You need to be able to access this port `80` running in your guest (ubuntu) from your host machine (windows).

In your `Vagrantfile` you can define port forwarding to do this. Add this line to your Vagrantfile as stated [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html):

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 80, auto_correct: true
```

If port `80` is already use in your host machine (windows) by another process/server/anything, you can set another port than `80` for the host like:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. I added the `AllowOverride All` flag in my `api.dukaan.pk.conf` file like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@api.dukaan.pk
    ServerName api.dukaan.pk
    ServerAlias www.api.dukaan.pk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
      AllowOverride All
    </Directive>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the explanation for this change to work as per **@tezla** comment

> based on the docs When this directive is set to All, then any
>   directive which has the .htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess
>   files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run lumen in subdirectory, use alias and this method worked for me, hope it helps somebody else.

In your Apache config file for which ever file is enabled in sites-enabled directory,

After your DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

add `Alias /api "/var/www/html/<directoryname>/public"` notice there is no trailing slash

and,

```
<Directory /var/www/html/<directoryname>/public>
      AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and rest are as it is. This should get the job done.